# MemSQL Spark connector inserting nulls from Spark to MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

I have this program which is reading parquet files and writing it into a MemSQL table. I can confirm Spark reading files correctly as

```
df.printSchema()
df.show(5)
```

correctly prints the schema and the data.

When I query the table, I get all NULL values for the rows. Everything is NULL in the table. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

The code which writes  parquet files to memsql

```
package com.rb.scala

    import com.memsql.spark.context.MemSQLContext
    import java.sql.{ DriverManager, ResultSet, Connection, Timestamp }

    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.RowOrdering

    import com.memsql.spark.connector._
    import com.memsql.spark.connector.OnDupKeyBehavior._
    import com.memsql.spark.connector.dataframe._
    import com.memsql.spark.connector.rdd._

    import scala.util.control.NonFatal
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    object MemSQLWriter {

    def main(arg: Array[String]) {

    var logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())

    if (arg.length < 1) {
      logger.error("=> wrong parameters number")
      System.err.println("Usage: MainExample <directory containing the source files to be loaded to database > ")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val jobName = "MemSQLWriter"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(jobName)
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val pathToFiles = arg(0)
    logger.info("=> jobName \"" + jobName + "\"")
    logger.info("=> pathToFiles \"" + pathToFiles + "\"")
    val dbHost = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
    val dbPort = 3306
    val dbName = "memsqlrdd_db"
    val user = "root"
    val password = ""
    val tableName = "target_table"
    val dbAddress = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort
    val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/projects/example/data/")
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbAddress, user, password)
    val stmt = conn.createStatement
    stmt.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + dbName)
    stmt.execute("USE " + dbName)
    stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(5)
    var columnArr  = df.columns
    var createQuery:String = " CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" ("
    logger.info("=> no of columns : "+columnArr.length)
    for(column <- columnArr){
       createQuery += column
       createQuery += " VARCHAR(100),"
    }
    createQuery += " SHARD KEY ("+columnArr(0)+"))"
    logger.info("=> create table query "+createQuery)
    stmt.execute(createQuery)

    df.select().saveToMemSQL(dbName, tableName, dbHost, dbPort, user, password, upsertBatchSize = 1000, useKeylessShardedOptimization = true)
    stmt.close()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a table with a SHARD key, and then setting `useKeylessShardingOptimization = true`, which will give undefined behavior.  Set this to false, and it should be good to go.

Also, I'm not sure what `df.select().saveToMemSQL...` does.  Try just `df.saveToMemSQL ...`

When verifying, do something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IS NOT NULL LIMIT 10` to see if you actually have all nulls.

PS: there is also `df.createMemSQLTableAs`, which does the thing you want.